# Properly escaping Json command line option in bash script

Tags: bash

I have utility which accept JSON as argument. How to escape json correctly to pass to the utility?
Example:

```
ip="127.0.0.1"
action='{\"server_ip\":\"$ip\",\"action\":\"stop\"}'
./fix-utility -e $action
```

But JSON is not getting escaped correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want interpolation of e.g. `$ip` inside the string, you need to use double quotes. Double quotes in the value need backslash escaping.

```
ip="127.0.0.1"
action="{\"server_ip\":\"$ip\",\"action\":\"stop\"}"
./fix-utility -e "$action"
```

Actually, I would advise against storing the action in a variable, unless your example omits something crucial which makes it necessary.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why I should not store action in variable ?

Comment: In this limited example, at least, it is a superfluous complication, especially if you ara not completely certain of quoting and evaluation rules.

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes and single quotes is not considered same by bash interpreter: While double-quote let bash expand contained variables, single quote don't. Try simply:

```
echo "$BASH_VERSION"
4.1.5(1)-release
echo '$BASH_VERSION'
$BASH_VERSION
```

At all, there is a nice reusable bash way:

```
declare -A jsonVar
toJsonString() {
    local string='{'
    for var in ${!jsonVar[*]} ;do
        string+="\"$var\":\"${jsonVar[$var]}\","
      done
    echo ${string%,}"}"
}

jsonVar[action]=stop
jsonVar[server_ip]=127.0.1.2

toJsonString
{"action":"stop","server_ip":"127.0.1.2"}
```

And finally:

```
./fix-utility -e "$(toJsonString)"
```

This could be improved if specials chars like `"` double-quotes have to be part of some strings.

Answer (score 1):

Updating this old question with newer tools. This solution relies on python's `jq` since it's a great tool for manipulating JSON files and strings.

Using the native bash string concatenation, one can do without having to escape anything manually and rely on `jq` to perform all the escaping.

```
# let's say I have need to include a variable within a string containing characters to escape
> my_string='a'"b"'c'
> echo -e "$my_string"
abc

> my_string='!(){'"$variable"'}[]'
> echo -e "$my_string"
!(){my_value_here}[]

# in effect, I'm concatenating these 3 strings together:
'!(){'
"$variable"
'}[]'
```

The single quotes prevent interpretation by bash, the double quote allow interpretation of the variable by bash.

Now, to escape, I would advise using python's `jq` program (`pip install jq`).

```
> ip="127.0.0.1"
> action='{"action":"stop","server_ip":"'"$ip"'"}'
> echo -e "${action}" | jq -cM '. | @text '
"'{\"action\":\"stop\",\"server_ip\":\"127.0.0.1\"}'"
```

For context, here are the versions of bash and jq that I'm using:

```
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> jq --version
jq-1.6
```